# Reducing the space dimension of a 3D pde using integration?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I have had this idea regarding reducing a 3D PDE to a 2D or even 1D PDE using integration; I am sure there is a more official and thorough method, so please let me know.

Suppose you have the simple heat equation defined in a 3D (possibly rectangular) box $\Omega=[0,l_1]\times[0,l_2]\times[0, l_3]$:

\begin{align}
u_t = \nabla\cdot(\nabla u)+g(x,y,z,t),
\end{align}
with boundary and initial conditions

\begin{align}
\vec{n}\cdot \nabla u = f(x,y,z,t), \quad u(x,y,z,0) = u_0.
\end{align}

Now suppose my goal is to reduce the dimension of the above PDE; maybe I want to get some sort of average in one of the direction (say $z-$direction) and be left with a 2D approximation of the above PDE.

What would be a good way of going about it? One naive way I thought about at first was to integrate my equations with respect to $z$ over my whole domain in the following manner:

\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega_z} u_t\ d\Omega_z = \int_{\Omega_z}\nabla\cdot\nabla u +g(x,y,z,t) \ d\Omega_z.
\end{align*}

I am not so sure how correct this is, but the main question is what will happen to my boundary conditions? Will it also be correct to integrade it (boundary conditions) with respect to $\Omega_z$. Furthermore, will it be correct to use the $z$-component  of the boundary condition to integrate the $z$-component of the gradient?

Thanks